# Change all available In-App Purchase products for newer app version

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

SCENARIO

Our app is already live in several versions. Let's treat below as an example:

- **Point A**: For App version1.0 to version3.0(already live), consumable IAPs available are listed below:

  1. item01
  2. item02
  3. item03
- **Point B**: For the current version and for future versions, we want to change the products from Point A to these consumable items:

  1. pack01
  2. pack02
  3. pack03

Our shop flow:

1. Game server sends product IDs to app (no app version filter).
2. App sends a request to Apple with the given IDs and displays the matching products only.

**Questions:**

1. How do we make a **safe** switch from Point A to Point B?

   - I'm thinking this will work (at least in theory) when executed in order:
   - 1. Add new product IDs to our server.
   - 2. Add new products to iTunesConnect. Mark them "cleared for sale" to Yes.
   - 3. Change the old products "cleared for sale" to No.
2. Will the steps in #1. mess up live purchases? What happens to those that are in the middle of purchasing, say the purchase was already successful in Apple side and we still need to verify receipts from our server, can our server still be able to verify receipts for products that were just set to "cleared for sale" No?
3. What are the list of products available once we implement steps from #1 for the current app version?
4. What are the list of products available for older versions once we submit version4.0(or above) and was approved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question which can only be answered by Apple support

Comment: Would be great to know if someone can answer having a similar experience but yeah, this can be closed as off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your game server is not filtering by app version.  I think you need to change that.  Once you mark the old products as not cleared for sale, any user who has not upgraded to your latest version will not be able to purchase the applicable SKUs.  Similarly any old installs will get the new product SKUs as available for sale and, I assume, not know what to do with them so users will end up paying and getting nothing (disaster).

My understanding of your other questions:
  2) Only Apple can say, but I suspect verification will work as the receipts are in some sense valid, just not current.
  3) The current app version will see the new products (yeah)
  4) The older version will see the new products (not yeah).

In summary:  either fix your server or point your new version at a new server.

Comment: Are you saying that IAPs are bound to versions in iTC? Meaning if in version 1 of your app, you have submitted pack1 and pack2, and in version2 you have added pack3(summing up to 3 IAPs), if the app with version1 queries for pack1, 2 and 3, Apple will just return the first 2 pack? 

Note that our server doesn't consider app versioning, meaning it gives the app all the available IAP IDs to all app regardless of its version. Our app can display products dynamically even if we change IAPs in iTC on the fly. Its the clear for sale that I'm not sure of.

Comment: The reason why we do not consider versioning when it comes to IAP is so app of all versions will have the same IAPs available for sale. We only sell in-game money which differs in amount per pack. ex. Pack1 = 100 coins. Pack2 = 300 coins. We wanted to change the IAP IDs to follow a different naming pattern, but the product details will be the same, hence the question about the "clear for sale".

Comment: I'm actually saying that IAP items are not bound to a version.  If all IAP items are valid in all versions then my concerns go away.  However, under those conditions, I'm not actually sure how things will respond in the boundary cases you list.  I'd be scared something will screw up.  Is there a compelling reason for changing the ids?